# How to add row in datatable using button click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I previously used datagridview but now changed it to use a datatable
`

```
        private void table()
        {
            //create a data set
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //create a data table for the data set
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //create some columns for the datatable
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Entry");
            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("SL");
            DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("SL%");
            DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("TP");
            DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("TP%");
            DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn("Position");
            DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("Day");
            DataColumn dc9 = new DataColumn("Notes");
            //add the columns to the datatable
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc5);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc6);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc7);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc8);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc9);

            //add the datatable to the datasource
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            //make this data the datasource of our gridview
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
        }
```

`

When using datagridview i used this code on a button click event to add a row
`dataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, EntryPrice.Text, StopPrice.Text, slper, ProfitPrice.Text, tpper, pos, day, NotesTB.Text);`

How do I add a row to the datatable with the same values using a button click event?

Using
`dt.Rows.Add`
isnt recognising the dt within my button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from another user

```
var devents = (DataTable)dataGridView3.DataSource;

DataRow newRow = devents.NewRow();
newRow["start_time"] = new_starttime;
newRow["stop_time"] = new_stoptime;
newRow["cycle_time"] = new_cycletime;
devents.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Credit to @kekusemau

Comment: You can turn the answer you find into an Answer, which makes it easier for other people with similar questions to find.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps you:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim table As DataTable = EEDataDataSet.Tables("Users")
        ' Use the NewRow method to create a DataRow 
        'with the table's schema.
        Dim newuserrow As DataRow = table.NewRow()

        ' Set values in the columns:
        newuserrow("Username") = Me.UsernameTextBox.Text
        newuserrow("Password") = Me.PasswordTextBox.Text

        ' Add the row to the rows collection.
        table.Rows.Add(newuserrow)
        yourTableAdapter.updateAll(EEDataDataSet)
            MsgBox("New User addition successful.")
            Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eddc0789-67f8-46ff-a35a-01d67a5e4944/add-a-row-to-a-datatable-from-a-form-button-click?forum=vbgeneral